# SQL find duplicate active records between two date ranges

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, a Patients table and an Insurance Table. One patient can have multiple Insurances. I am trying to find all Insurances that have overlapping active dates or that show two as being active.

```
PATID    START_DTTM           END_DTTM
1        2002-09-10 00:00:00.000  NULL
1        2007-03-06 10:18:00.000  2019-04-11 11:59:00.000
```

If END_DTTM is Null then it is active. A start date should start when the subsequent end date ends. I am trying to find all entries where the active dates overlap or that it shows two active entries for a period if that makes sense?

Also to add to the mix an Patient can have multiple insurances, the above example shows a patient with two insurance details. they could also have a third or fourth entry...

Any help would be great

Comment: What is the desired result ? Suppose a patient has 4  Insurances effective at a paticular date, say 2007-03-06. Then what a result should a query produce?

Comment: To return all patients and insurances that have overlapping active dates. and then someone can go into the system and correct this data. If one patient had 4 overlapping insurance details then I would like to return all 4 @Serg

Comment: OK overlapping insuarances are (a,b,c) (c,d) (d,e,f)  What the result should a query produce? Just 6 rows a,b,c,d,e,f  or what?

Comment: Yes if it returns all I guess that would be fine. Basically the dates should not over lap at all. And if they do return the insurance so that we can correct it on the system. Insurance details migrated in which is causing overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list all insuarances which has at least one other insuarance overlapping.

```
select ID, PATID, START_DTTM, END_DTTM
from insurances i1
where exists (select null 
              from insurances i2
              where i1.ID != i2.ID and i1.PATID = i2.PATID
                and (i1.START_DTTM  <= i2.END_DTTM or i2.END_DTTM is null)
                and (i2.START_DTTM  <= i1.END_DTTM or i1.END_DTTM is null)
             )
order by PATID, START_DTTM;
```

Two active insurances (null end date) are considered overlapping. You may wish to change `<=` to `<` if equal start /end dates are not considered overlapping.

Comment: This seems to be returning non duplicates as well? patient a with insurance start date 01012018 end date 01012019 then a new insurance will start from 01012019 and a null end date. this is active and doesnt overlap so this shouldnt be included. but seems to be included in your code above?

Comment: @Conger88, no it will not return an insurance just because null end date. Only if there exists other insuarance which ends after this one starts or has null end date too. Two active insurances ( null end date) are considered overlapping.

Comment: I changed the <=  to < and i think that done it now! Thanks a mill!!

Answer (score 0):

If your insurance table also has a unique id for each insurance (we would hope so) then you could have a query like this

```
declare @tab table (
    patid int
    , insid int
    , start_dttm datetime
    , end_dttm datetime
)

insert into @tab values (1, 8, '2002-09-10', NULL)
                        , (1, 9, '2007-03-06', '2019-04-11')
                        , (53, 321513, '2015-01-13', NULL )
                        , (53, 11, '2008-08-14', '2015-01-13')
                        , (54, 12, '2015-01-13', NULL )
                        , (54, 13, '2008-08-14', '2015-01-12')

select      a.*
            , b.*
            , 'Insurance record ' + cast(b.insid as varchar) + ' (' + convert(varchar,b.start_dttm,103) + ' to ' + convert(varchar,b.end_dttm,103) + ') '
             + 'overlaps Insurance record ' + cast(a.insid as varchar) + ' (' + convert(varchar,a.start_dttm,103) + isnull(' to ' + convert(varchar,a.end_dttm,103), ' still active') + ')'

from        @tab a
inner join  @tab b
on          a.patid = b.patid
and         a.insid != b.insid
where       (b.start_dttm > a.start_dttm and b.start_dttm < isnull(a.end_dttm, getdate()+1))
or          (b.end_dttm > a.start_dttm and b.start_dttm < isnull(a.end_dttm, getdate()+1))
or          (a.end_dttm is null and b.end_dttm is null)
```

Note - You would not need to create a table variable @tab like I have done, just use your  insurance table.

Comment: Yes the insurance table has a unique id. ok so I used your query as below with my table select      *
from        dbo.PATIENT_INSURANCE_DETAILS a
inner join  dbo.PATIENT_INSURANCE_DETAILS b
on          a.PATNT_REFNO = b.PATNT_REFNO
and         a.PATIN_REFNO != b.PATIN_REFNO
where       b.start_dttm between a.start_dttm and isnull(b.end_dttm, getdate()+1)
or          b.end_dttm between a.start_dttm and isnull(a.end_dttm, getdate()+1)
ORDER BY a.PATNT_REFNO  This looks to return valid entries also. so I dont want to include entries that dont overlap

Comment: There was a typo in my query so I have edited. Also added another clause to catch scenarios where patient has multiple insurances that are active

Comment: This still seems to be inlcuding valid non overlapping entries? example below

PATIN_REFNO PATNT_REFNO PERCA_REFNO START_DTTM END_DTTM
321513 53 NULL 2015-01-13 00:00:00.000 NULL
11 53 NULL 2008-08-14 23:59:00.000 2015-01-13 00:00:00.000